# Manual update of CPE.BIN file on Garmin Solar Instinct

Tags: gps, garmin

Trying to update CPE.BIN ([Connected Predictive Ephemeris](https://support.garmin.com/en-US/?faq=6IbaJEHc1i9gydzQomXzyA)) file on Garmin device without using proprietary Garmin Express / Garmin Connect app.

There is documentation on the Internet about EPO.BIN files, but I can't find anything about CPE files.

- Is there any available info about the file format?
- Is there any known source for those files? Could be Garmin, Sony (GPS chip provider) or third-party. Or a recipe to craft the file from public information.
- Where should the file be put on the watch file tree when used in mass-storage mode?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question:

CPE file should be in the REMOTESW folder (sports & fitness devices).

You can manually request update from Garmin Express, just delete the contents of the REMOTESW folder and sync with Garmin Express.